# What is meant by Solid Mesh and Surface Mesh?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solid-mechanics, simulation, ansys, meshing

Solid Mesh vs Surface Mesh, which method should I choose in simulation studies. What is the geometry behind these meshes. Which mesh gives accurate results?

Comment: Packages like Ansys will give the definitions of exactly what they implement in the help files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of them ***potentially*** give accurate results. The accuracy of the results depends mainly on the application and the correct use.

As a general rule

- Surface meshes are usually more appropriate with sheets of metals. (the width and length have values that are much greater than the thickness).
- Solid meshes are usually more appropriate for parts that all the dimensions are in the same order of magnitude.

Apart from that basic rule, there are many asterisks.

Comment: All down to the first law of simulation (or calculation): Garbage in means Garbbage out...

Comment: I didn't want to be that explicit, but it has crossed my mind.